# Bash keeps throwing "syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to write a shell script to copy and rename files, and I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows subsystem for Linux.  I'm currently just at the "copy" part, and I have the following, with `<path>` standing in for my file path.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "<sourcepath>"/*; do echo "$file" && cp "$file" "<destinationpath>"
done
cd "<destinationpath>"
```

The script appeared to execute correctly until I added the `cd "<destinationpath>"` line.  Now the console says "syntax error: unexpected end of file".  I don't have any newlines or anything I can think of that would be causing this.

The last two lines of hexdump -c:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a carriage return in that last string? That would cause the file ending without a closing double quote. Try `dos2unix` on the file.

Comment: Why would it cause that? You're allowed to have a CR inside a string.

Comment: Why would you put `cd` at the end of a script? It doesn't have any effect because the process exits immediately.

Comment: You could also look at the file using [`hexdump`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) to see unprintable or space characters (like wrong newlines).

Comment: If you edit that shell script and put an enter at the end of the last line (I guess the "cd" line), does it stop complaining?

Comment: I put an enter at the end of the last line, but that didn't change the error unfortunately.  Hexdump shows that after "done", there is \r \n, and then there is one more line that is blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dos2unix on the file, and I was able to run it without errors.